# How to get two id values from php in javascript AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

How to get two id values from php in javascript AJAX

**test.php**

```
function lc(str) {
    if (str.length == 0) {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "gethint.php?q=" + str, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
} 


<p>Output1: <span id="txtHint"></span></p>
<p>Output2: <span id="wrdHint"></span></p>
```

**gethint.php**

```
<?php
$q=$_GET["q"];

if (strlen($q) > 0)
  {
  $out1=strlen($q);
  }
if (str_word_count($q) > 0)
  {
  $out2=strrev($q);
  }
echo $out1;
echo $out2;
?>
```

**Output1 is only working**

**Output2 not working.**

Can anyone please help me....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your php code, and output both ids separated by comma 
ex:

```
<?php
$q=$_GET["q"];
$out1="";
$out2="";
if (strlen($q) > 0)
  {
  $out1=strlen($q);
  }
if (str_word_count($q) > 0)
  {
  $out2=strrev($q);
  }
echo $out1.",".$out2;

?>
```

Then in your javascript

use

```
var str = xmlhttp.responseText;
var arr = str.split(',');
// arr[0] will be the first id
// arr[1] will be the second id

document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = arr[0];
document.getElementById("wrdHint").innerHTML = arr[1];
```

Comment: Thanks. getting output2 as undefined. Please help

Comment: yes ,I given the same
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    var str = xmlhttp.responseText;
    var arr = str.split(',');
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=arr[0];
    document.getElementById("wrdHint").innerHTML=arr[1];
    }
still not working...

Comment: <?php
$q=$_GET["q"];
$out1="";
$out2="";
if (strlen($q) > 0)
  {
  $out1=strlen($q);
  }
if (str_word_count($q) > 0)
  {
  $out2=strrev($q);
  }
echo $out1+","+$out2;

?>

Comment: @RamyaLoveRamya can you give me the link to you php file

Comment: function lettercount(str)
{
if (str.length==0)
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  document.getElementById("wrdHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    var str = xmlhttp.responseText;
var arr = str.split(',');
document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=arr[0];
document.getElementById("wrdHint").innerHTML=arr[1];
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","gethint.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}

Comment: <textarea id="text" onkeyup="lettercount(this.value)"></textarea>
<p>Output1: <span id="txtHint"></span></p>
<p>Output2: <span id="wrdHint"></span></p>

Comment: @RamyaLoveRamya Thats my mistake, use echo $out1.",".$out2;

Comment: @RamyaLoveRamya Last but not least if you are sure that you will get output for $out2 in every case then its fine, but in the condition $out2 ="" you will get undefined.

Comment: @RamyaLoveRamya so better you put a condition in javascript, that if(arr[1]) the only assign a value to respective span

Answer (score 0):

Join both values together and then separate them in your jquery function. 
Another way is to encode them in json with key value pair using json_encode(). Then it will be more easy to parse them.