# How to get value from ajax on same page of php

Tags: javascript, php

I want to get value from ajax on same page i used html php and javascript

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#godown').change(function() {
        var gownid = $(this).val();
        alert(gownid);
        $.ajax({
            url: '../inc/safedispatch_detail.class.php',
            method: 'GET',
            data: {gownid:gownid},
            success: function(result){
            }
        });
    })
});


</script>
```

and my php code is:

```
echo $_POST['gownid'];
```

showing me blank output. Please guide whats wrong in this

Comment: `echo $_GET['gownid'];`? You are making `GET` request, according to your js

Comment: `$_POST`  but you're doing `method:'GET'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get two id values from php in javascript AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19492376/how-to-get-two-id-values-from-php-in-javascript-ajax)

Comment: Use `$_REQUEST['gownid'];` will give all POST and GET

Comment: You can get the AJAX output in Developer Tools > Console.

Comment: `echo '{ "gownid":"'.$_GET['gownid'] .'"}';`

Comment: @ Jaromanda X   i have used post on both places but did not get from this also,thats why i changed it

Comment: not getting from $_REQUEST also.

Comment: do you have anything in your alert(gownid) ? İf yes so assure that the given url is correct.

Comment: yes ,showing id in alert

Comment: _“showing me blank output”_ - where? Where did you look for it, or perhaps even more important, where did you _expect_ it to show? You are not doing anything with the server’s response in your success callback handler, so what did you expect? This sounds like you are not even aware what AJAX basically _is_ tbh.

Comment: showing me blank when i getting value in php

Answer (score 0):

Your method is **GET** so if your code is :

```
echo $_POST['gownid'];
```

It will not work ;)

- change your method to POST or your php code to

  echo $_GET['gownid'];
- then you can test the value returned with developper tools or :

  success: function(result) {
  alert(result);
  }

or

```
success: function(result) {
console.log(result);
}
```

- if the result is what you expect, you can i.e. write the php returned html in your html page ie

  success: function(result) {
  $('#myid').text(result); // for a p paragraph field
  }

or

```
success: function(result) {
$('#myid').val(result); // for an input field
}
```

Comment: its showing blank when i alert this success: function(result) { alert(result); }

Comment: Are you sure 1/ that your var gownid is not empty 2/ your url is correct? You should use the developper tools to check what is happening... what is your internet browser? I recommend https://www.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/developer/, then CTRL + SHIFT + K to access to the developper tools.

Answer (score -2):

What is good with js ajax request is to have your method type as 'POST'.

so if in your jquery change event your alert is not empty then in your php it will just work fine.